# reset value back on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, reset, var

Each time I am resizing my browser smaller then 1600 width I am adding 5 from my value of 100. However, when I declare my else condition it does not reset the value back.

```
 var resizeNum = 100
 var resizeNumReset = resizeNum

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1600 || $(window).height() < 1020) {
        resizeNum += 5;
    }
    else {
        resizeNum = resizeNumReset;
    }

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `width.height()` be `$(window).height()`?

Comment: ^^^ getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: width is not defined"

Comment: replace width.height() with jQuery(window).height()

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about just a strange typo ?

Comment: My fault that was a typo on my ending I edited the post. Moving forward its still doesn't reset the value

Answer (score 0):

This is simply caused by a typo:

You have a condition `$(window).height() < 1020 < 1020`. This will evaluate to `false < 1020` or `true < 1020`, which will always evaluate to `true` (boolean will be casted to int: `+false === 0` and `+true === 1`). This will cause the if-statement to be always true, which will cause the else-block to be never executed. Remove the rogue `< 1020`.

```
if ($(window).width() < 1600 || $(window).height() < 1020) {
```